# Quickly searching a doubly linked list

Tags: c, search, linked-list

I currently have a simple database program that reads keys in from a text file and stores them in a doubly linked list (values are read later if they are required). Currently, I do a sequential search on the list, but that is clearly rather slow. I was hoping that there is another way to do. I was reading about binary trees (in particular, red black trees) but I don't know to much about them, and was hoping that I could gleam something from the stackoverflow hivemind :) I suppose my question is, what is the fastest way to do a search in a doubly linked list?

EDIT: Forgot to say that the list is sorted. Don't know if that changes anything. Also, the reason I only read in keys is that the max value length is 1024*32 bytes, which I feel is too large. Note that this is for an assignment, so "typical usage scenarios" don't apply. The professors are likely going to be stress testing the hell out of this thing, and I don't want to be mallocing blocks that big.

Comment: Binary trees and linked lists are different data structures (lists are a degenerate form of trees).  So you have to consider whether you are willing to change the structure.

Comment: Beware the performance cost of reading the text file twice; it is likely to be better to read and save the values as you read the keys.  Files are *s*l*o*w* and memory is generally cheap.

Comment: A quick fix would be, use a hashmap to store the list node's pointer against the key :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a thing called a "[skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)" that you could use.

It is a set of ordered lists. Each list skips more of the list items. This lets you do a form of binary search. However, maintaining the lists is more difficult.

Comment: This seems really promising. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to do a search in an unsorted doubly-linked list is one element at a time.

If you're trying to make search faster, don't use a linked list. Your idea of using a binary tree, for example, will certainly be faster, but as Matthew Flaschen said in comments, it's a completely different implementation from what you're using now.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your doubly-linked list is sorted, and you have a list of items to search for, I suggest looking into the problem of building a self-balancing binary search tree. The tree construction could take some time, but it will be amortized if you have a long list of items to search for.